# `CREATE USER PASSWORD` vs `CREATE USER WITH PASSWORD` in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, keyword, difference

Based on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createuser.html

Does anyone know the difference among the 2, or they are basically the same?

```
CREATE USER user0 PASSWORD '123'
```

---

```
CREATE USER user0 WITH PASSWORD '123'
```

seems to me `WITH` is a keyword which does nothing, because both commands are workable. But, I wish to confirm on this.

Comment: We call that a "noise word". You can insert it if it makes you feel good, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's precisely what the `[ ... ]` part means: Optional.

Answer (score 0):

`WITH` is optional so the SQL below using no `WITH` and `WITH` are the same according to [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html):

```sql
CREATE USER user0 PASSWORD '123'
```

```sql
CREATE USER user0 WITH PASSWORD '123'
```